# Bind event to ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using this snippet to show a spinner once a link is clicked. Some times the link `.ln-edit-task` is loaded via Ajax, and the snippet breaks. How do I make it work on Ajax loaded content?

```
jQuery(document).on("ready page:change", function() {
  return $(".ln-destroy-task").on("confirm:complete", function(e, response) {
    if (response) {
      return showSpinner($(this));
    }
  });
});
showSpinner = function(el) {
  return el.find(".fa").removeClass().addClass("fa fa-spinner fa-spin");
};
```

Note that `page:change` is required by Turbolinks in Rails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).on("confirm:complete", ".ln-destroy-task", function (e, response) {
    if (response) {
        return showSpinner($(this));
    }
});
```